# Code to ask confirmation before Delete pictures

Tags: excel, vba, image

I code to delete all the images that are in the column "A1:A40". I would like to add code so that confirmation is asked before the photographs are deleted.

The idea is to prevent a mistake on the button from immediately deleting all the photographs in this column.

I have two codes that work. I want to combine one with the other?

I tried to insert the second code in the first one. When the text box appears, clicking on the "Yes" or "No" button, the code deletes all the photos.

The first code:

```vb
Sub DeletePic()
    Dim xPicRg As Range
    Dim xPic As Picture
    Dim xRg As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xRg = Range("A1:A40")
    For Each xPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        Set xPicRg = Range(xPic.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & xPic.BottomRightCell.Address)
        If Not Intersect(xRg, xPicRg) Is Nothing Then xPic.Delete      
        
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Range("A2:A36").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 33
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 32
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 31
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 30
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 29
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 28
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 27
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 26
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 25
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 22
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 21
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 20
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 19
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 18
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 17
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 16
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 14
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

This final part of the code (ActiveWindows.ScrollRow = A2:A36) is a little bigger because I made it recording a macro for this part of the code.

The second code that I want to insert in the first:

```vb
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response, MyString
Msg = "Deseja continuar ?" 
Style = vbYesNo 
Title = "Esta operação apagará todas as fotografias"  
        
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
If Response = vbYes Then   
    MyString = "Yes"  
Else    
    MyString = "No" 
End If
```

Comment: just an additional suggestion you can delete also the activewindow.scrollrow lines and just use `Range("A2:A36").ClearContents`

Comment: Thank you k1dr0ck, now, the code is faster with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ask the user to confirm that they want to run `DeletePic` you need to add your second block of code at the top of `DeletePic` (anywhere before the `For Each` loop)

Your second block of code currently doesn't really do anything with the result.
You can simplify it to something like the following:

```
Dim Result As VbMsgBoxResult
' ask if they want to continue
Result = MsgBox("Delete Pictures?", vbYesNo, "Confirm")
' if they do not, then exit out otherwise continue
If Result = vbNo Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: NickSlash, a huge thank you!. You solve me the code problem